# How to connect to ElastiCache instance (Redis) from Django App running on local machine

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm struggling to find a solution to properly set connexion between my Django app running on my local machine and my ElastiCache instance

Let me resume the situation.

### CONFIG:

I have a Django App deployed on an AWS EC2 instance and running using a docker-compose-yml file. I'm using ElastiCache & Redis for my cache.

### MY ISSUE:

I can successfully connect to my ElastiCache Instance from my EC2 instance. I can use Redis and create key etc.. Everything working perfectly.

I am able to connect to ElastiCache from my Django App when I run it with my docker-compose.yml file within my EC2 Instance.

I can also use Redis on my ElastiCache from my local machine by creating a sort of bridge with my EC2 instance using this command:

`ssh -f -N -L 6379:{my_elasticache_amazon_url}:6379 ec2-user@{my_ec2_instance_url}`

Then I run the following command and have access to redis:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

But I can't access to ElastiCache from my Django App running on my local machine! I need to set this connexion for dev and test purpose, before deploying it on the EC2 instance.

### WHERE I AM:

I tried to directly connect to ElastiCache using the URL in the Django App but access is not allowed since the security group in AWS is set to only accept connexion from the EC2 instance.

`redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to {my_elasticache_url}:6379. Connection refused.`

I tried to put 127.0.0.1 & localhost as the URL for connexion since I made a link between my local machine and EC2 instance with the previous command, but it's not working, I have the same error:

`redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.`

I already tried to set `network_mode: "host"` in my docker-compose file but it's not working since I have some port binding.

### RESSOURCES:

**Code line in my Django App to connect to Redis:**

```
import redis
import os

r = redis.Redis(
    host=os.environ.get('CLUSTER_HOST', default="127.0.0.1"), port=6379, db=0)

my_key = r.get('my_key')
```

**Port Listening command on my local machine:**

```
lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN 
ssh   22744 username  7u   IPv6 0x254006fa8c767523   0t0     TCP [::1]:6379 (LISTEN)
ssh   22744 username  8u   IPv4 0x254006fa9cfbe91b   0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:6379 (LISTEN)
```

**Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:**

```
version: '3.9'

x-database-variables: &database-variables
  POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
  POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${ALLOWED_HOSTS}

x-app-variables: &app-variables
  <<: *database-variables
  POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
  SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID: ${SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID}
  SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET: ${SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET}
  SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
  CLUSTER_HOST: ${CLUSTER_HOST}
  DEBUG: 1

services:
  website:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    environment: *app-variables
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment: *database-variables
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - website
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static
      - ./files/templates:/var/www/html
      - ./proxy/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  static-data:
  db-data:
```

**Inbound Rules of the Security Group of my ElastiCache Instance:**

[image]

**Inbound Rules of the Security Group of my EC2 Instance:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using AWS VPN as explain in [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws).

You just have to setup a VPN network linked to the ElastiCache, you can then set permissions to allow specific user to connect to it (or you can make it public). After that, you just have to connect to VPN from your local machine as explain at the end of the documentation.

You can then use Redis the same way I do on my EC2 instance.

**From your machine:**

```
redis-cli -c -h your-elasticache-name.l5ljap.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

**From your Django App:**

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(
    host=your-elasticache-name.l5ljap.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com, port=6379, db=0)
```

**Tips**: Don't forget to connect a Router that has access to Internet, otherwise you'll not be able to connect to internet from your machine as soon as you are connected to the VPN (that can be annoying when you are making API request in your app for exemple).